# Is large alignment considered costly in general situations?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, system

#### Background

I am writing a piece of code for an in-memory b-tree. For some reason, I will need to be able to locate the node given a pointer to the element inside the node. I hope to achieve this with alignment:

```cpp
  struct Node;
  static constexpr size_t larger_power_of_two(size_t x) {
    size_t i = 1;
    while (i <= x) {
      i <<= 1;
    }
    return i;
  }

  static constexpr inline size_t HEADER_ALIGNMENT = larger_power_of_two((2 * B - 1) * sizeof(T));
  static constexpr inline size_t ALIGNMENT_MASK = HEADER_ALIGNMENT - 1;

  struct alignas(HEADER_ALIGNMENT) NodeHeader {
    alignas(T) uint8_t storage[(2 * B - 1) * sizeof(T)];
    Node *parent;
    uint16_t usage;
    uint16_t parent_index;
    NodeType type;
  };
```

Then, I should be able to locate the node via:

```cpp
Node* node_of(const T * ptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Node*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr) & ~ALIGNMENT_MASK);
}
```

For this specific use case, `B = 6` is preferred and the data type `T` is something like `void *`. I hope the tree is portable, so 32/64-bit (or even 128-bit platforms like CHERI) pointers are considered.

#### Question

I am not sure whether doing this may become too costly: either in the sense of memory waste due to alignment padding or in the sense of the fragmentation/workload of commonly used allocators.

#### What I have known

I know that another way to do the pointer "relocation" is to add an index (uint64_t) to each block of T. But, it seems to use more space. Moreover, extra computational work is required to maintain the indices during b-tree operations.

Comment: I would reorder the Node and NodeHeader struct, have the metadata in front and align/pad. That will always have a constant size (no need for calculations). And then the node info is in front of your data, all you have to do is to substract that constant size from your data address

Comment: @PepijnKramer the idea is essentially to find the beginning of `storage` given a pointer to any element inside `storage`. Reordering will not help you here.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  What I understood is that OP tries to find the pointer to the element/Node from its data pointer.

Comment: @PepijnKramer "locate the node given a pointer to the element inside the node". A node in a B-tree has an array of elements.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks that clarifies a lot... I forgot about the 'array' of elements in a B-tree (and assumed it was just a node)

Comment: There are no generic recipes that work for everyone. Everything is a trade-off. Measure how different approaches perform *in your application*.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is allocating nodes in blocks, and then performing a two-stage locating procedure.

First, find the block. You probably want to have an array of block pointers sorted by address and run a binary search. A BST of blocks will also work.

After finding the block, calculate node index within the block. This is  trivial since you know the block address and the size of the node.

There is no need to worry about alignment with this approach.